# Integration Services Catalogs - Version Description

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

In Integration Services Catalogs I can see what versions of a package/project are available and if necessary revert to an older version. On this dialog I see a field "description" however I found no way yet to put a description into this field. How can it be edited/filled ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're describing this window

[image: Project Version dialogue]

## What the answer wasn't

Folder's have descriptions, you can set them via the [catalog.set_folder_description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878043.aspx) stored procedure. In my example, my folder is called SSISHackAndSlash and my project is SSISHackAndSlash2012.

[image: SSISDB]

I called the above method and looked at the properties of the folder and they match.
[image]

I then tried to use the same call but using the Project name but no dice

```
EXECUTE catalog.set_folder_description 
    @project_name 
,   @folder_description = 'called from set_folder_description'
```

> Msg 27104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure set_folder_description, Line
>   73 Cannot find the folder 'SSISHackAndSlash2012' because it does not
>   exist or you do not have sufficient permissions.

That's the only public proc in the list of all the SSISDB [Stored Procedures](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878099.aspx) that mentions description.

The actual deploy proc, [catalog.deploy_project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878004.aspx) doesn't have a parameter for description.

### What the answer *is*

Since the answer wasn't in the public catalog and it lead me to believe it either wasn't an exposed property or it's something in the actual project itself. Occam's razor wins.

[image: project properties]

Win

[image: Description shows]

If you like futzing with the .ispac directly, in the @Project.manifest, the property is serialized under the `<SSIS:Properties>` node as `<SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Description"></SSIS:Property>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the description property on the package itself and not the folder, it can either be set in SSDT by entering a value in the appropriate property field, or, after deploying to the IS Catalog, by running an update query on the internal.packages table in the SSISDB.

Hope that helps.